# httpd cache rules with query string

Tags: apache, http, query-string

i'm using the following apache rule to cache my images for 1 year

```
<Location ~ "/images">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    FileETag none
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    Header set Cache-Control "public,  max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000"
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Location>
```

but if i added a query string to my image url its ignore the query string and and serve from the cached version it should new version and hit the server

example of my query string request

```
images/969532/470/320/800.jpg?pattern=true
```

Any tips to adjust the cache rule to respect the query string and hit the server again ?

Comment: Would you please show your request headers?

Comment: here is my  response here

Answer (score 0):

Try use [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) directive instead of `Location`.

Comment: already tried  that but not helping , its keep ignore query string and serve cached version

Comment: Try add `$` in URI like `<LocationMatch ~ "/images$">`